# How to join 3 tables or more in one msql query

Tags: mysql

Normally I make something like this.

```
#1 first query
 while () :
    #2 2nd queries
    #3 3rd queries
 endwhile;
```

to get a result. Now I want to combine them in one query. How can be done with this.

```
Table#1
-------------------------------------------
SELECT 
UserID, UserName, CountryCode, StateCode, CityCode, VillageCode, UserRace, UserStatus, UpdateStatus 
FROM user_locality
WHERE CountryCode = '{$getCountryCode}'

Table#2
-------------------------------------------
SELECT 
* 
FROM user_addresses 
WHERE address_UserID = '{$UserID}'

Table#3
-------------------------------------------
SELECT 
phone_UserID, phone_m, phone_h, phone_o 
FROM user_phones 
WHERE phone_UserID  = '{$UserID}'
```

Thank you.

Comment: You understand that if a user has 10 addresses and 10 phones, the combined query will return 100 rows (for that user only!) ? Your first approach is probably more efficient, I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `JOIN` clause. There are different types of joins. I'm using `LEFT JOIN` below which will select all records from `user_locality` and try to match records from both `user_addresses` and `user_phones`.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      `user_locality`
LEFT JOIN `user_addresses`
ON        `user_addresses`.`address_UserID` = `user_locality`.`UserID`
LEFT JOIN `user_phones`
ON        `user_phones`.`phone_UserID` = `user_locality`.`UserID`
WHERE     `user_locality`.`CountryCode` = '{$getCountryCode}'
```

The one thing to point out this query will result in more than 1 row for each user that has more than 1 phone or address.

Comment: Thanks francois. I have about 500k data on each table. There have a way to not use the `SELECT *`.

Comment: @lampard - Of course, I wasn't sure what fields you wanted but you can add the list of fields in place of the `*`. If the field shows up in more than one table, add the name of the table followed by a dot in front of it (i.e.: `user_locality`.`User_ID`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. If I got `field list is ambiguous` that's mean my column name is not same?

Comment: @lampard - Yes. Add the table name in the front followed by a dot and that'll save your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, something like this should work:

```
SELECT (fields you want) FROM user_phones, user_addresses, user_locality WHERE user_locality.CountryCode = '{$getCountryCode}' AND user_phones.phone_userID = user_locality.UserID AND user_addresses.address_UserID = user_phones.phone_UserID
```

In general, the beauty of SQL  is that you can specify MULTIPEL tables in the FROM field, thus allowing you to do a join by stating the conditions for keeping a combination of rows in the results. For example, if you do

```
SELECT * FROM table_a, table_b
```

You'll get every possible combination of rows. So if A has 10 rows and B has 25, you'll get 250 result rows! Adding WHERE table_a.something = table_b.something will give you what you want.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tips on `WHERE`.

Comment: Implicit joins with `WHERE` is really old, very old syntax. Use explicit `JOIN`.

Comment: Not sure I agree. Explicit JOIN is the prettiest way to do it in this case, and usually is for plain joins (although it's really much better when the PKs are all titled the same, which is not so here). But I feel there was PEDAGOGICAL value in teaching WHERE instead. Based on the question, they clearly were not aware you could do that. Teaching about explicit JOIN feels like teaching "yet another" magic syntax for that particular task. I wanted to give the asker the tools to figure out their next problem on their own. For that task, WHERE is more intuitive and general, even if not as pretty.

Comment: Just to be clear, I do agree that the explicit JOIN is the best way to solve this particular problem. Just thought the asker was best served by slightly deeper SQL education, rather than a cut/paste approach. Teach a man to fish and all that.